# Merging mp4 video files on Android

Tags: java, android, video, merge, mp4

I am capturing a video in my android app and saving it . Now  I want to merge two mp4 files together and play it .
I am not able to merge the mp4 files as I am not aware of mp4 header structure . 
Can anybody guide me how to go for it ?

Comment: Playing them one after another is not an option, I guess? (Like a playlist?)

Answer (score 5):

Using Mp4parser has solved my problem . I am able to merge mp4 video files .
Library Link-[http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser](http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/)

Comment: Hey man, can you share the code you used to merge the two MP4 files together?

Answer (score 0):

This [code for the video editor](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/media/libvideoeditor/) may be able to help you.